# Set up Responsive filemanager on TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, file-upload, tinymce-4, file-manager, responsive-filemanager

I'm using TinyMCE 4 as my WYSIWYG editor and I've installed [Responsive Filemanager](http://www.responsivefilemanager.com).

I've tried to follow the instructions very carefully, but when I preview the page the "browse" button doesn't appear.

I'm currently working localhost on my computer so my folder structure looks like this:

htdocs > websites > example (root), so the url is h**p://localhost/websites/example

folder structure:

```
example
- css
- uploads
- source ( this is the upload folder )
- thumbs ( thumbnail folder )
- filemanager
-- config
--- config.php
- js
-- tinymce
--- plugins
---- responsivefilemanager
----- plugin.js , plugin.min.js
```

The config looks like this:

```
$url = ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'localhost') ? 'h**p://localhost/websites/example' : 'h**p://www.example.com' ;
$base_url = $url; 
$upload_dir = '/source/';
$current_path = '../source/';
//thumbs folder can't put inside upload folder
$thumbs_base_path = '../thumbs/';
```

and this is the javascript on my page that sets TinyMCE

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea.tinymce", 
        entity_encoding : "raw",
        // menubar: false,
        subfolder:"content",
        plugins: [
            "link image media anchor responsivefilemanager", 
            "code"
        ],
        // toolbar2: "| responsivefilemanager | link unlink anchor | image media | forecolor backcolor  | print preview code ",
        image_advtab: true,
        // external_filemanager_path:"/filemanager/",
        // filemanager_title:"Responsive Filemanager" ,
        // external_plugins: { "filemanager" : "/responsivefilemanager/plugin.min.js"}
        // toolbar: "undo redo | styleselect | bold italic underline | 
        // alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that it was an error on config.php.

Solution:

```
$base_url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];  // DON'T TOUCH (base url (only domain) of site (without final /)).
$upload_dir = '/websites/example/uploads/source/'; 
$current_path = '../uploads/source/'; 
$thumbs_base_path = '../uploads/thumbs/';
```

also init the javascript like this:

```
external_filemanager_path: "/websites/example/filemanager/",
filemanager_title: "Responsive Filemanager" ,
external_plugins: { "filemanager" : "/websites/example/filemanager/plugin.min.js"}
```

Comment: How to upload .ttf and other extension files? 
Where shall I write the .ttf and other files for uploading support to "Responsive file manager".
When I upload the .ttf file in it, it says "File extension is not allowed".
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have written <div class="input-append">
   <input id="fieldID2" type="text" value="">
   <a href="filemanager/dialog.php?type=2&amp;editor=mce_0&amp;field_id=fieldID2" class="btn iframe-btn" type="button">Select</a>
 </div>